# In OS X Yosemite, FileVault, "Enable Users" is not available

Tags: macos, filevault

This is an inconsistency I've found compared to Apple docs on this, and to all the answers in forums online, and to another laptop in my care, similarly configured.

My user account is an Admin account.

Even after unlocking the preference pane for FileVault, "Enable Users" is not an option. Every help page or web search I've found has shown the "Enable Users" button in a screenshot of the prefs pane.

However, other users can still log in from the login screen!

Can anyone explain this behavior? I need to know what's up so I can administer my office's population of 20 or so Mac users.

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The <kbd>Enable Users…</kbd>-button is only available in the Preferences Pane *Security & Privacy* > *FileVault* if one or more users is/are **not** enabled to use FileVault.

You may test this yourself: open Terminal and enter:

```
sudo fdesetup list
```

to list all FileVault enabled users

Remove one user:

```
sudo fdesetup remove -user user_name
```

wait a few seconds and open *System Preferences* > *Security & Privacy* > *FileVault*.

[image]

[image]

Quit *System Preferences* > *Security & Privacy* > *FileVault*.

Add the user again:

```
sudo fdesetup add -usertoadd user_name
```

and enter some passwords/recovery keys.

Open *System Preferences* > *Security & Privacy* > *FileVault* et voilà: the button is gone.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Thing that I don't understand is that I did add a couple of users, but I never added them to FileVault. Are new users added to FV automatically in some circumstances?

Comment: @JDS New users added after enabling FV or all users configured before enabling FV are added automatically